# How to do Disk Partition in Linux Ec2 server of size 8gb using a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-ec2

I am very new to shell script.
I have an ec2 server linux, t2.micro , 8GB.
I want to create a disk partition of 2.5 GB and 5.5 GB.
All the commands I got from internet .
My current disk space looks like :
'''

```
[root@ip-172-31-32-43 ec2-user]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/xvda: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D9A255FF-D4AA-4A93-888D-AF818AFCEEC1

Device       Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/xvda1    4096 16777182 16773087   8G Linux filesystem
/dev/xvda128  2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
```

'''

and after running parted -l :
'''

```
[root@ip-172-31-32-43 ec2-user]# parted -l
Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvda: 8590MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                 Flags
128     1049kB  2097kB  1049kB               BIOS Boot Partition  bios_grub
 1      2097kB  8590MB  8588MB  xfs
```

'''
After looking on help I got vbelow shell script to do this :

'''

```
(
  echo o;
  echo n;
  echo ;
  echo ;
  echo ;
  echo +2548M;
  echo a;
  echo n;
  echo ;
  echo ;
  echo ;
  echo ;
  echo w;
) | fdisk /dev/xvda

mkfs.ext4 -n 'BOOT' /dev/xvda
```

'''

When I run this as part of shell script :
below comes as output in putty console :
'''

```
Command (m for help): The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Re-reading the partition table failed.: Invalid argument

The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8).

mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
mkfs.ext4: invalid blocks '/dev/xvda' on device 'BOOT'
```

'''

ok now to verify if I run fdisk -l command , I feel like partition is successfull ,

'''

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x792c79d4

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/xvda1 *       2048  5220351  5218304  2.5G 83 Linux
/dev/xvda2      5220352 16777215 11556864  5.5G 83 Linux
```

'''

but when I stop and start the server . it never starts . Dont know what is breaking ?

if I am doing it correct way and is there any other way or shell script to achieve this disk partiton of root volume .

Comment: Why are you partitioning disks on a VM? Just use two separate AWS EBS instances.

Comment: In actual scenario we will be spinning up an ec2 sever with 100 GB root instance , and then it will be separted to 60GB and 40 GB.

Comment: Why not add one 60GB EBS instance and one 40GB instance?